# How are the sub folder's mergeinfo used when merging at top folder level?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

As we know, TortoiseSVN creates `svn:mergeinfo` as a folder property if the merge is performed at that folder level. This could be a top folder (such as **trunk**) or some sub folder. I always thought that it was OK to merge at sub folder level since the `svn:mergeinfo` on the sub folders would be used when merging at the top folder level.  I think that it was generally working for me as well in the past, until today when I saw a case that I could not explain.

I saw a merge at sub folder level from a **branch** to **trunk** and I could see at that revision an `svn:mergeinfo` property on that sub folder at **trunk** as well.

However if I try to merge from **branch** to **trunk** again at the top folder level, that merged revision at branch is not greyed out. If I try to merge, it would just merge the property at the top folder without really any code change.  If I try to merge one folder up from that sub folder, that merged revision is not greyed out as well.

I could not explain what I saw here. Could anyone shed some light on this?  I am using the latest TortoiseSVN 1.8.1. In the past I was using TortoiseSVN 1.7 and below. Has the latest version of TortoiseSVN changed the behavior for this intentionally or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use tricks, which you don't understand fully
2. Don't use tricks, when they aren't needed (subtree merges is a must **in a rare, some special cases only**)
3. Read relevant part ("Subtree Merges and Subtree Mergeinfo" topic) from [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html) **gently, slowly, without haste**

And now, considerations regarding your question:

- When you *merge some revisions* in subtree, in means nothing for parents - because for parents of any level these revisions **are not merged** (even if they haven't any objects outside subtree)
- Mergeinfo of subtree used only for avoiding duplicated merge *in this subtree* (not above or below), when *the same revision(s)* merged later to some parent (and moved to merge-root of parent, when such merges with intersected revision (in subtree and parent merges) is done)