# Merge New Folders from Trunk into an existing Branch using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

What are the steps to merge/add a new folder to a branch from the trunk? For example, if I have the following branch structure:

`branches\new_branch\folder_A`
`branches\new_branch\folder_B`
`branches\new_branch\folder_C`

And wish to add a few folders that had not been merged/added to the branch folder but do exist in the trunk, how do I do that with TortoiseSVN? e.g.

`trunk\folder_D`

And end up adding this folder to `new_branch`:

`branches\new_branch\folder_D`

I only want to add this specific folder as opposed to bunch of other new ones.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answer to your question, but this looks like [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you really want to do? I'm asking, because I'm working for years with svn and I never have to merge only single folder from trunk to branch.

Of course if you really want to do this, you should read an answer to this question: [How are the sub folder's mergeinfo used when merging at top folder level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366235/how-are-the-sub-folders-mergeinfo-used-when-merging-at-top-folder-level) Remember that this is not much better than just copy-paste your folder with mergeinfo in subdirectory that you may never use.